# Identifier "initSol()" is undefined

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

I've been writing some C++ code and I face an annoying problem : "identifier initSol is undefined" !! My project is devided into 3 files : 
instance.h which contains the data strutures (struct) "solution" and "problem"
coupe.cpp which uses the defined structrues and creates methods like :

```
solution * initSol (problem * pb)
{
solution * s;
int * tab, used,i,selected;
    for (i = 0;i<pb->nbTotPcs;i++)
        s->elem[i] = 0;
used = 0; i = 0;selected = 0;
tab = eclatement (pb);
while ((used < pb->tailleBarre) && (i<= pb->nbTotPcs))
{
    used+=tab[i];
    s->elem[i] = 1;
    selected++;
}
s->nbTaillesDem = pb->nbTaillesDem;
s->objVal = used;
s->tailleBarre = pb->tailleBarre;
s->tailleTot = used;
s->nbElem = selected;
return s;
}
```

main.cpp : this is the main file in which I call initSol :

```
int * tab = (int *) malloc (prblm->nbTotPcs * sizeof(int));
solConst = initSol(prblm);
```

and here I got the problem

> "identifier initSol is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```
extern solution * initSol (problem * pb);
```

should go into the header, after the structs

Comment: also make sure to include the header in your main.cpp